# python - invalid values for bool

Tags: python, boolean

What are invalid values for the `bool()` function? I mean which arguments make it throw exceptions?

As far as I know any custom data structure is `True` and empty list, empty strings etc. are false.

So are there any values for `bool` arguments that make it return other than "True" or "False"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `bool()` can only return `True` or `False`. **All** values in Python have boolean meaning.

If the value is not an empty container, numeric 0, `None` or `False`, `bool()` returns `True`.

Note that `bool()` will use the [`__len__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), [`__nonzero__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) (Python 2) and [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) (Python 3) special methods if present; if these throw an exception `bool()` will not catch it.

Comment: The only somewhat common type that I can think of off the top of my head with an exception throwing `__nonzero__` is `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: @mgilson: so is Martijn wrong to say that "all values in Python have boolean meaning", or are the numpy authors wrong to say, "the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"? Or (as I suspect) is the answer to that question above either of our pay grades? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Python feels all values have a boolean value; `numpy` uses exceptions correctly to signal that the question should not be asked of certain values.